# Searching a string for a substring of characters in a list

Tags: python, list, file

> sp|P46531|NOTC1_HUMAN Neurogenic locus notch homolog protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=NOTCH1 PE=1 SV=4
>   MPPLLAPLLCLALLP

I have a fasta file and I would like to search the file for the beginning of the amino acid sequence. It would be something like

```
aminoacids = ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename,'r') as fh:
        while True:
        char = fh.read(1)
        if char.upper() in aminoacids:
            #look for the 4 characters directly after it
```

but if a character is found to be in the amino acid list and the four characters next to it are also in the list, then a string will be made starting with that character and going until there are no more characters.
For example, I would like to iterate through the file looking for characters. If M is found, then I would like to look for the next four characters (PPLL). If those next four characters are amino acids, then I would like to create a string starting with M and continuing to the end of the file.

Comment: The 4 characters you are looking for, are they in the fasta file or you mean if 'A' then print 'A' 'C' 'D' 'E'?

Comment: @Andy Wong My bad, I'll fix that wording. I mean in the file. I am looking for characters in the file.

Comment: How large is the file? Is it plausible to read in the entire file into memory at the start? (The only reason you might not is if you expected the sequence of amino acids to be very near the end of a very large file)

Comment: @DavidRobinson The file is not too large at the moment. I am only dealing with relatively small files. I have converted it into a string later, but I wanted to search the file first. If I have to, I could convert it into a string first. Would that be better?

Comment: just fyi, but every letter is a valid amino acid one letter code, because there are some for "uh, it's either this one or that one but we're not sure they're chemically similar". B is asn/asp. Z is glu/gln. X is unknown. J is leu/ile. u is selenocysteine and O is pyrrolysine

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I know.. I just would like to use the characters in this list. I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. I believe that fasta files use the abbreviations in this list only...

Comment: Hum. I'm getting the format from here: http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blastcgihelp.shtml . Is it true that the amino acid sequence will always start on a newline?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Yes it always does start on a new line. But just in case I get a corrupted file (e.g. someone tampered with it and emailed it to me) I want to make sure my code works.

Comment: Right now, your code has a chance of accidentally matching something in the description. (for example, matching CHIC in OVAX_CHICK GENE X PROTEIN).

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Yes I will make it look for 10 letters after the first letter perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the file as a single string, and then search for a regular expression:

```
regex = re.compile("[%s]{5}.*" % "".join(aminoacids))

with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    s = fh.read()
    aa_sequence = regex.findall(s)
    if len(aa_sequence) > 0:
        # an amino acid sequence was found
        print aa_sequence[0]
```

This works because the regular expression that is constructed is:

```
[ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY]{5}.*
```

which means "5 of these characters, followed by anything."

Note that if your amino acid string may span multiple lines, you'll need to remove the newlines first, with:

```
s = fh.read().replace('\n', '')
# or
s = "".join(s.readLines())
```

Comment: `aa_sequence = regex.findall(s)[0]` for this I get a list index out of range error...? I had completely forgotten that python had regex like perl, so thanks for that.

Comment: @varda1316 Ah: that means the file had no amino acid sequence. See edit for a version that tests for this

Comment: I don't think that this works because A) my file was not empty to begin with - there was an amino acid sequence B) now it just says that there is only 1 character in the file when I print `len(aa_sequence)`...? I think perhaps I have to put this in a loop for it to work?

Comment: @varda1316 It is not saying there is only 1 character in the file, it is saying it found one match. Print `aa_sequence[0]` and you will see that it is the matching string.

Comment: Ohh that works. Now about the list index out of range error that I got before, I actually had a file with only lowercase letters which was the problem. So basically aa_sequence is a list and when I print the length, it tells me there is one element in the list?

Comment: @varda1316 Yes; It's a list that either has 0 elements (if no string with five amino acids was found) or 1 element (meaning the string was found, and is included as the first element).